# Is Bithiah, Moshe's "mother", also the wife of Shlomo Hamelech?

Tags: sources-mekorot

The Encyclopedia of Biblical Personalities records two Bithiah's in Tanach. One is the mother of Moshe (as in Shemos and 1 Chronicles 4:18). The second is the wife of Shlomo Hamelech (1 Kings 3:1) which also happens to be "the daughter of Pharaoh" (see. Berachos 8a).

Is this the same Bithiah or no?

Comment: Gosh, if they were the same she'd be sooooooo old.

Comment: The name of the daughter of Pharaoh that King Solomon marries is not mentioned.

Comment: Reminds me of the old question about Naamah mentioned in Beresheis being Noach's wife (see Rashi).

Comment: @ezra Targum Kesuvim [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Divrei_HaYamim_II/8.11#e0n7) claims that the daughter of Pharaoh that Shlomo married was Bisyah

Comment: @רבותמחשבות that's an answer! Why don't you post it as one?

Comment: @ezra No, it doesn't.  Perhaps it was the daughter of another Pharaoh, and she was also named Bisyah.

Comment: This reminds me of Muhammad claiming that Miriam the mother of Jesus is the same Miriam as Moshe's sister.

Comment: @ezra Bisiya never died. Certainly possible.

Comment: @DonielF Source for that statement?

Comment: @ezra Same Braisa in Derech Eretz Zuta ([1:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Derekh_Eretz_Zuta.1.18)) that lists all the others who went into Gan Eden alive.

Comment: @DonielF Is that to be taken at face value though? Rabbi Akiva and Acher also supposedly went into Gan Eden alive.

Comment: @ezra If you’re referring to ארבע נכנסו לפרדס that’s something very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst noting @DonielF's comment above from [Vayikra Rabbah 12:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.12.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we can't necessarily assume it is the same person.

Indeed from a historical viewpoint, the Pharaoh during the time of Moshe is generally regarded as being [Rameses II](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12086-pharaoh) (ca 1279– 1213 B.C.E.) and as such his daughter would have been incredibly old by the time she married Shlomo. Moreover, it says expressly in [Shir HaShirim Rabbah 1:6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.1.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אָמַר רַבִּי לֵוִי יוֹם שֶׁנִּתְחַתֵּן שְׁלֹמֹה **לְבַת פַּרְעֹה נְכֹה**
>
> *Rabbi Levi said the day that Shlomo was married **to the daughter of Pharaoh-Necoh***

[Pharaoh-Necoh](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11410-necho) lived 610 to 594 B.C. - so quite a bit later. This seems to tally as we know that Pharaoh-Necoh coveted Shlomo's throne (see [Yalkut Shimoni 1046](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1046.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it says that Necoh had the throne moved from Yerushalayim to Egypt and then in [Pesikta d'Rav Kahana 26:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_D%27Rav_Kahanna.26.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where we're told he didn't know how the throne worked and a gold lion from the throne injured him.)

Finally, as a technicality, it brings in the Gemara ([Yevamos 76b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.76b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that she wasn't actually his wife, rather she was a pilegesh (concubine) - but because he loved her so much (Also refer to the [Sifrei Devarim 52](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.52.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it notes he loved her more than all the others) it is considered as if he married her.

Comment: I'm not sure the relevance of your Rameses II point. Regardless of his identity, she was older than Moshe (as she raised him), so automatically she'd be very old if she married Shlomo. Unless you just wanted to give historical dates, instead of relying on the Jewish dates of when Moshe was born.

Comment: @Robev it was more to ascertain historically which paroh was in place and as such to show that if she was the daughter of the same one she would be hundreds of years old. The fact that there are sources showing that she was the daughter of Neco, a later King, and not the same pharoah from Moshe's time hopefully proves that it was a different lady..

Answer (score 1):

No. First of all, it must be clarified that Moshe's mother was Yocheved. Bitya found Moshe in the Nile and rasied him as his adoptive mother.

Second of all, "Bithiah" is not mentioned in the verse from Melachim, only "Pharaoh's daughter", so I see no reason to assume they are the same person. It's clearly a different Pharaoh with a different daughter.

Comment: Vayikra Rabbah 12:5: “Once [Shlomo] built [the Beis HaMikdash] and married Bisiya bas Paroh...”

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bithia bas Paroh mentioned in Divrei Hayamim I 4:18 as the wife of a man named Mared. The Malbim is unsure if this is a man named Paroh or Paroh the king of Egypt. The Gemara in Megillah identifies her as Basyah the daughter of Paroh who raised Moses and converted to Judaism. So we actually do know who the mother of Moses married; it was Mared, who Chazal identify as Kalev ben Yefuneh (rashi there). [sources](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.4.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&p2=Rashi_on_I_Chronicles.4.18.3&lang2=he&p3=Megillah.13a&lang3=he)

As to whether she could be the same daughter of Paroh married to Solomon, the verses in Kings say that Solomon built the temple 480 years after the Jews left Egypt. Occam's razor says this is a different daughter of Paroh. In addition, the daughter of Paroh is listed among the foreign women that Solomon married (Kings I 11:1). The original Bithia was not a foreigner, as she would have been part of the Jews for hundreds of years. [sources](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.6.1?lang=he&p2=I_Kings.11.1&lang2=he&p3=Rashi_on_I_Kings.11.1&lang3=he)

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, the fact that she married calev proves nothing, as he surely died before Shlomo lived. I think your main proof is she wasn't a foreigner. Who says she was a foreigner?

Comment: @robev I edited it to incorporate your comments.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it became Egyptian Tradition that because Bisya, who was living at the time of Moshe was such a Tzadekes not only to the Jewish nation but to the Egyptians as well her name became very Choshuv in the Egyptians' eyes and they decided to use that name when naming a girl similar to what occurs not only in Jewish tradition but in the secular world.

So essentially yes there are 2 Bisyas in Tanach,  the one who was around at Moshe's time, and the one who married King Shlomo, but it could have been that there were many others as well.

Comment: No idea why you think the Egyptians called her that. Most likely it was simply her Jewish name like basya is today. What makes you think it was  an Egyptian name.